# Reading mails through gmail apis

Tags: java, gmail-api

I am trying to build an application which needs to read mails of user once authorised. As a starter, I want to know, whether gmail allows third party applications to do so, if yes, how to get started on it.

Comment: you tagged your question with "gmail-api" ? possibly start searching there ?

Comment: Hey Sid, I did go through the apis documentation, it mostly says auth support, till now I could not find anything which allows me to read mails, that is why seeking help for a starting direction.

Answer (score 1):

> Does Google allow third party access?

Yes. If you're going to be doing interactive programming using mainstream services, learn to use APIs. The Google API collection allows users to register their applications and sites for a *huge* variety of their services...including `Gmail`.

Look [here](https://console.developers.google.com/) for more details.

> How can I get started?

Read the documentation and instructions for overall Google-API usage in the link above, *and* the separate documentation for the service you want to use.

For `Gmail`, look [here](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/).

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the others its fairly well documented, particularly here would be relevant for you if you intend to get started using the Java API:
[Google docs](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/java#step_3_set_up_the_sample)

> To run this quickstart, you'll need:
>
> Java 1.7 or greater. Gradle 2.3 or greater. Access to the internet and
>   a web browser. A Google account with Gmail enabled....